# jQuery Validate: make field only required if option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I use the jQuery Validate plugin and would like to make a select field only required if another select field has a selected option. Here comes my code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-form">
   <input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput">

   <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="myOtherSelect" name="myOtherSelect">
       <option value="">Please select</option>
       <option value="1">Other option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Other option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Other option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $('#my-form').validate({
                    debug: true,
                    rules: {
                        myInput: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        myOtherSelect: {
                            required: function () {
                                return $(this).find('[name="mySelect"]').val() != '';
                            }
                        }
        }});
```

How do I manage that the select field "my-other-select" is only required when an option has been selected for the field "my-select"?

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a05jrdau/1/

Comment: thanks, yeah, it looks fine. let's assume we want to use a find-selector to find the "mySelect" field. why does the adapted code not work? http://jsfiddle.net/a05jrdau/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a05jrdau/3/ - `this` inside the function refers to the window object...

Answer (score 4):

Your code works fine, but as per your comment I think what you are after is

```
$('#my-form').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        myInput: {
            required: true
        },
        myOtherSelect: {
            required: function (el) {
                return $(el).closest('form').find('.mySelect').val() != '';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a05jrdau/)

Comment: why would `parent` instead of `closest` not work?

Comment: @Doro that will depend on the html, with your current markup it works - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a05jrdau/4/

Answer (score 1):

From http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ :

```
$("#myform").validate({
  ignore: ".ignore"
});
```

You can add an class for which validation is ignored, and remove it when the value is selected.